# how to test STDIN with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Ok, need help working out a test. I want to test that this class receives a letter "O" and 
that when called the "move_computer" method returns WHATEVER the person enters on the cli. my mental subprocessor tells me this is a simple assign a variable to something to hold the random human input at STDIN. Just not getting it right now...anyone point me in the right direction?

here is my class...

```
class Player
  def move_computer(leter)
    puts "computer move"
    @move = gets.chomp
    return @move
  end
end
```

my test look like...

```
describe "tic tac toe game" do
  context "the player class" do
    it "must have a computer player O" do

      player = Player.new()
      player.stub!(:gets) {"\n"} #FIXME - what should this be?
      STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("computer move")
      STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("\n") #FIXME - what should this be?
      player.move_computer("O")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `move_computer` *returns* the input, I think you meant to say:

```
player.move_computer("O").should == "\n"
```

I would write the full spec like this:

```
describe Player do
  describe "#move_computer" do
    it "returns a line from stdin" do
      subject.stub!(:gets) {"penguin banana limousine"}
      STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("computer move")
      subject.move_computer("O").should == "penguin banana limousine"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I came up with...

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'

# the universe is vast and infinite...it contains a game.... but no players
describe "tic tac toe game" do
  context "the player class" do
    it "must have a human player X"do
      player = Player.new()
      STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("human move")
      player.stub(:gets).and_return("")
      player.move_human("X")
    end
    it "must have a computer player O" do
      player = Player.new()
      STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("computer move")
      player.stub(:gets).and_return("")
      player.move_computer("O")
    end
  end
end
```

[NOTE TO THE ADMINS...it would be cool if I could just select all my code text and right indent in one button push. (hmmm...I thought that was a feature in the past...?)]

Comment: There's an button that looks like `{}` that I think does what you describe.