# Write test for displaying output of array

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want `puts` each element of an array. How to write test for that?

Comment: I think this link should be helpful for you: [how to test STDIN with RSpec][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222175/how-to-test-stdin-with-rspec

Answer (score 0):

Testing `puts` can be hard because it's inherently non-deterministic. Also, it's safe to assume that the ruby interpreter you're using has very good test coverage for it, so the payback on writing your own would be minimal. I think you want to test your array manipulation code, rather than `puts`.