# disable warnings when testing thor CLI

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, thor

I have a CLI app that uses the [thor](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/wiki) gem.

My tests pass, but because I am testing the API directory, I get a lot of warnings:

```
All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:focus=>true}
.......
[WARNING] Attempted to create command "__email_dir?_without_any_instance__" without usage or description. 
Call desc if you want this method to be available as command or declare it inside a no_commands{} block. 
Invoked from "/Users/julieng/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-mocks-3.1.2/lib/rspec/mocks/any_instance/recorder.rb:211:in `alias_method'".
```

I have `ENV['RACK_ENV']='test'` in my `spec_helper.rb` file, which according to a SO search, was supposed to help.

I found some other SO threads ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673485/how-to-test-stdin-for-a-cli-using-rspec)), but I am not testing any input, just calling API methods directly.

This is just annoying. Any ideas on how to resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a shotgun approach, but when I *really* want to suppress message cruft from the command line and keep the test output clean, in my tests I'll just stub out `$stdout`s output stream eg:

```
describe CLI do
  before do
    allow($stdout).to receive(:write)
  end

  # your tests here ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you, that's worked beautifully. I'm also only applying to the CLI specs as per your example. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You can get a slightly more targeted approach than Paul's steamroller-style approach with something like this:

```
describe MyCLI do
  before do
    class Foo < StringIO
      def puts s 
        super unless s.start_with?('[WARNING] Attempted to create command')
      end
    end
    $stdout = Foo.new
  end

  after do
    $stdout = STDOUT
  end

  # your tests here...
end
```